# how to clone a VM on LVM to another in KVM?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, debian-wheezy, cloning

On a Debian wheezy i installed KVM for virtualization and install some VMs on it. I use separate LVM disks because of its performance for my VMs disk.

Now i need to clone one of them in new LVM disk. I searched too much for it and i found `virt-clone`, but unfortunately The `virt-clone` just clone Vms with disk in files and cannot clone LVM disks. I think it is possible by `dd` like so:

```
dd if=/dev/vg_kvm/lv_disk1 of=/dev/vg_kvm/lv_disk2
```

Is there any more optimize solution? How can i clone my VM which is installed on a LVM disk to a new LVM disk?

Comment: What was wrong with my question for down vote it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LVM volumes as targets for the copy without a problem

```
virt-clone -o source_system --name new_system --file /dev/vg_kvm/lv_disk2
```

should do the trick. It handles the source block device (instead of a file) as well.

Comment: If i do so, Is there any problem for network-UUID and VM-UUID? If so, how to solve it?

Comment: No, there is not. Please read the `virt-clone` man page. Cite: `Elements which require uniqueness will be updated to avoid a clash
between old and new guests.`  What has this to do with whether you use a file or a LVM volume as a target anyway? Either `virt-clone` handles this correctly or it doesn't, but it wouldn't make a difference depending on the target device. Remember: A block device *is* a file, that's one of the core principles of Unix: Devices are files.